# How to create proxy in PHP

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I'm trying to create a proxy in PHP. When I visit the page http://example.com everything is OK, but using cURL, I always get a 401 Unauthorized Error.

My code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, getallheaders());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com');
print_r(curl_exec($ch));
```

The response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 20 Oct 2016 01:30:11 GMT
Content-Length: 1293
```

Comment: Have you tried other urls? A 401 error typically means the type of communication is refused. This could be as simple as a website requiring the visitor to login, or as sofisticated as a strict security policy on the server that only allows communication from well-known browsers. Although such security is unusual, it is possible.

Comment: Hello, yes I tried another. But the result is same. I know the problem is in authentication, but I'm trying to simulate same environment as browser is, that is why I forward all headers, co there is also information about browser etc. So I can not see any reason why it does not work.